# Get all layers including operators from torch in python

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torch, yolo

I want to get all layers like convolution etc... and operator like "add" in python but I really dont know how.

This is my code

```
import torch

# An instance of your model.
model = torch.jit.load('best5.torchscript')

# Print all the layers
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    print(name, param.shape)
```

It works fine but problem is that I am able to see only layers like convolutional not all with operators. How can i fix that?

For example in this image I can see everything when model is loaded to netron
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `named_parameters` to `named_modules` and print `module` (in your case `param`) instead of `param.shape`

Comment: Wow yes it seems to work. Sadly it does not work this nicely in c#. Problem solved anyway thank you :)